# И еще о конской упряжи. Слово "уздечка"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Пока писала предыдущий вопрос, озадачилась другим.
Часто в текстах встречаю слово "узда", есть даже поговорка "держать в узде". Но на конном спорте весь комплекс "оголовье + повод" мы учили как "уздечку". Также уздечкой называют в анатомии части, ограничивающие движение какого-то органа. Рисунок на морде дельфинов тоже называют "уздечкой".
Так все-таки как правильно: "узда" или "уздечка"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узда, уздечка (как упряжь)- общелитературные синонимы

ОГОЛОВЬЕ - в словарях помета (спец.), т.е. профессионализм.
В словаре конного спорта (http://www.racessport.ru/index.php?lang=rus&id=5337 )написано: ОГОЛОВЬЕ - основная часть конского снаряжения, надеваемая на голову лошади и позволяющая управлять ею; то же, что узда. Различают трензельное и мундштучное оголовье.

В анатомии уздечкой называется тонкая складка слизистой оболочки, которая удерживает губы и язык в правильном положении.Это анатомический термин. Видимо, образовался как омоним от первонач. значения "то, что сдерживает, удерживает".Рисунок на морде дельфинов внешне похож на уздечку - узду.

Так что всё правильно. Просто если это термины, то нужно говорить так, как термин принят в науке. Если говорим не как профессионалы, а как обычные граждане, слова узда и уздечка в упряжи - синонимы, выбирайте любое.